# Why does my element work on first click but not second click?

Tags: css

I set up a CSS dynamic snippet on my site and it behaving strangely, when you click on the icons it works, but if you click twice it scrolls up a few pixels up.

Click on the 5 icons repeatedly and you will see that they work on fist click but not on the second consecutive click, something wrong with the toggle?

Comment: Questions about [coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should be asked over on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), and website troubleshooting is also considered off-topic for this site. If you do ask on Stack Overflow, you'll need to provide the code that you're working with in your question so that it will be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function` on line 1410 which is `$(document).ready(function(){`

That is likely the cause.  Fix that and then see what happens

Comment: In what files is that located, I'm not familiar with reading JS errors yet, that script  I pasted from somewhere and changed it to css, not sure if JS powers it?

Comment: No idea. You are the web designer.

Comment: Doesn't chrome dev tool point to the file location? I'm not familiar with JS, I stripped out all JS and it's working with CSS only...not sure about the JS part...;(

Comment: It does, but you need to do some of the work your self ;o)  http://www.xuzo.com/sites/default/files/js/js_MyvSZrd_pIc7oj6Nu1wsrxnJLtWZdh7EeIaYuyzPO48.js

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use Jquery which is a javascript library/extension.  Before calling the $ function you may need to use `jQuery.noConflict();`  Usually these types of errors are related to conflicts between javascript libraries/extensions/modules/etc.